# R error: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r, plot

I need to make an exercise in which I plot "abo" from a csv datafile. I imported the data file and got to writing the plot, but I keep receiving this error.

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I tried to transfer the character variables of the "abo" column to factors. However, this did not work and I kept receiving the same error.

```
transplant <- read.csv("transplant2.csv")
transplant
age <- transplant$age
boxplot(age) ## plot a boxplot
hist(age) ## plot a histogram
abo <- transplant$abo
factor(abo)
plot(abo) ## this row gives me the error.
```

Why does this happen, and how can I solve it?

Comment: If you want to convert `abo` to a factor, you need to reassign it e.g. `abo <- factor(abo)`. What does your data look like? Are there `Inf` or `NA` values in your data?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839784/error-in-plot-window-need-finite-ylim-values-spc-charts-in-r

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions with this error. When you wrote this question you were informed of a question with a duplicate title (which is why you added "help appreciated" to the title). It is often worth reading the possible duplicates, as you might get your answer faster.